# Attach blazor component dynamically

Tags: blazor

Can I create an instance of a Blazor component in C# and attach it afterwards?
Alternatively can from C# code dynamically create a component in the DOM and get back a reference to it?

I'm creating a "popup dialog" triggered from the C# code.

**Dialog.razor**

```
<div>
    Dialog Text: @Text
</div>

@code{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Failed attempt**

```
<div>
    @foreach (var d in List)
    {
        <div>@d</div><!--this doesn't work since d is not a RenderFragment-->
    }
</div>

@code{
    public List<Dialog> List { get; set; } = new List<Dialog>();

    void AddDialog()
    {
        var d = new Dialog();
        d.Text = "Hello " + List.Count;
        List.Add(d);
    }
}
```

Problem here is that I haven't found a way to attach an instance of ComponentBase onto the DOM.
Is there a way to get the RenderFragment?

Secondary problem is that child components aren't initialized until after the dialog is attached thus limiting what can be done in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is another way to do it...

### AlertMessage.razor

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 500px; height:auto; margin: 3px; 
  padding:0px;">
    <div style="height:auto; width:inherit; padding:5px; border: 1px solid 
    blue; text-align:right;">
        <span style="float:left">@Title</span>
        <a href="#" @onclick="@(() => Close.InvokeAsync(ID))" 
   role="button">X</a>
        <div><input type="text" value="@content" /></div>
    </div>
     <div style="padding:25px; ">@ChildContent</div> 

 </div>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  [Parameter]
  public string Title { get; set; }
  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback <int> Close {get; set;}

}
```

### AlertMessageGroup.razor

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices;


<h3>AlertMessageGroup</h3>
@if (alerts.Count > 0)
{
<p>Contains @alerts.Count AlertMessage Components</p>

@foreach (var alert in alerts)
 {
       <p>Alert ID: @alert.ID</p>

 }
}

<div>

    @foreach (var alert in alerts)
    {
        @RenderAlert(alert);

    }


</div>



@code {

List<Alert> alerts = new List<Alert>
        {
            new Alert{ ID = 1, Title = "First Message", Message = "This is my 
                                                            first message" },
            new Alert{ ID = 2, Title = "Second Message", Message = "This is 
                                                        my second message" },
            new Alert{ ID = 3, Title = "Third Message", Message = "This is my 
                                                             third message" }
        };


private RenderFragment RenderAlert(Alert alert) => builder =>
{

    builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(AlertMessage));
    builder.AddAttribute(1, "ID", alert.ID);
    builder.AddAttribute(2, "Title", alert.Title);


    builder.AddAttribute(3, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)((builder) =>
    {
        builder.AddContent(4, alert.Message);


    }
    ));

     builder.AddAttribute(5, "Close", EventCallback.Factory.Create<int>
                                          (this, RemoveAlertMessage));
     builder.CloseComponent();

  };



public void RemoveAlertMessage(int ID)
{

    alerts.Remove( alerts.Where(alert => alert.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault());
    StateHasChanged();
}


public class Alert
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

}

}
```

### Usage

```
@page "/"

<AlertMessageGroup />
```

Comment: Am I correct that the instance stored in the list is not the same instance as is rendered. Meaning if I implement a method SetMessage() that calls StateHasChanged(), it won't be called on the rendered component but rather the instance in the list.

Comment: I do not create a list of components to render. I create a list of Alert objects passed a parameter to the RenderAlert method which renders the components. When I want to remove (or add ) a component, I remove (or add) an Alert object from the list of Alert objects, and then call the StateHasChanged method, which tells the parent component that its state has changed, and that it should re-rendered.

Comment: "it won't be called on the rendered component but rather the instance in the list. " The StateHasChanged method is rather a simple method whose role is to notify a component that its state has changed... that is all. It is up to the component whether to re-render or not. If you store a list of components, and changes the values of these components, nothing actually happens, unless you call the StateHasChanged method to notify the component that its state has changed, resulting in re-rendering, if applicable.

Comment: Your components  stored in the list of course contain new values you assigned to them, and the re-rendering reflects that.

Comment: I see, every render will recreate with updated properties.

Comment: I couldn't get this to run.
I made three razor pages and used the 'Usage' code my Index.razor.
The error trap was lit up like a Christmas tree.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it

1. Create a `Placeholder` object and place it in a list
2. From the list the razor page will create a new instance.
3. Catch the instance reference and pass it back to the calling code
4. Wait for `OnAfterRender` before operating on the instance.

**Dialog.razor**
Unaware of it being loaded dynamically.

```
<div>
    Dialog Text: @Text
    <Red @ref="Red"></Red>
</div>

@code{
    public Red Red { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public void SetText(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

**DynamicWrapper.razor**
For notifying when the component is fully loaded

```
@ChildContent

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback AfterFirstRender { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await AfterFirstRender.InvokeAsync(null);

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
}
```

**TestPage.razor**

```
<div><button @onclick="AddDialog">Add one more</button></div>

<div>
    @foreach (var p in List)
    {
        <DynamicWrapper AfterFirstRender="p.AfterFirstRender">
            <Dialog @ref="p.Dialog"></Dialog>
        </DynamicWrapper>
    }
</div>

@code{
    public class Placeholder<T>
    {
        public T Dialog { get; set; }

        TaskCompletionSource<T> task = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        public void AfterFirstRender(object args)
        {
            task.SetResult(Dialog);
        }

        public Task<T> GetDialog() => task.Task;
    }

    public List<Placeholder<Dialog>> List { get; set; } = new List<Placeholder<Dialog>>();

    async Task AddDialog()
    {
        var p = new Placeholder<Dialog>();
        List.Add(p);
        var d = await p.GetDialog();
        d.SetText("Hello");
        d.Red.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very creative way around this problem.   Works very well!